# How to add a custom xml layout when a tab is selected from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I got the following code from github but i need to know how can i add a custom xml layout when getItem() method is called. Can anyone help please?
Right now the app shows the CONTENT String only, i need to add a different custom layouts each time a tab is swiped or seleced.

```
public class SampleTabsWithIcons extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Calendar", "Camera","Alarms", "Location" };
private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
        R.drawable.perm_group_calendar,
        R.drawable.perm_group_camera,
        R.drawable.perm_group_device_alarms,
        R.drawable.perm_group_location,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
}

class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
//This is the part i need help
   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override public int getIconResId(int index) {
      return ICONS[index];
    }

  @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.length;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just you need to create different Fragments for each layout(if those are different one). Create the instance of each Fragment and return in getItem() method.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0)
            return AFragment.newInstance();
        else if(position==1)
            return BFragment.newInstance();
        else if(position==2)
            return CFragment.newInstance();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! But it accepts only Java Classes with Fragments ectended. How can i make it to set a class with extended Activity?

Comment: We have to use Fragment only for FragmentAdapter. So you can do that only. Anyhow, it is better practice to use the Fragments.